# CFLAGS for C++ (GNU compiler) not working

Tags: c++, flags, compiler-flags

Im compiling a c++ file with the gnu compiler `g++`. For C I use CFLAGS but its not working for c++. What Im seeing the .cpp files using the -O2 flag but `g++ -Wall *.o -o tp2` is compiling without the flags.

I added it manually to tp2 but now the flags are not being used `compile`. So my question is how do I fix this. Ive also tried with `CXXFLAGS` and `CPPFLAGS`. Thanks.

```
.PHONY: link clean
CFLAGS:= -O2 -Wall 

Make:   tp2
compile: coordonnees.o personne.o tp2.o

%.o: %.cpp %h

clean:
        rm -rf tp2 *~ *.o
tp2: compile
        g++ -Wall *.o -o tp2
```

Comment: It should be spelled `CXXFLAGS`.

Comment: `g++ -Wall *.o -o tp2` is the linker invocation, not the compilation step. Why do you expect it to use the `CFLAGS` or `CXXFLAGS`? `-Wall` and `-O2` have no meaning for linking step. Linker flags are given in `LDFLAGS`.

Answer (score 0):

`CFLAGS` and the like only apply to the implicit rules of `make`. Since you defined the command as `g++ -Wall *.o -o tp2` instead of depending on an implicit rule, it runs exactly that command. If you want to add those flags you can put `$(CFLAGS)` on the line where you define the command.